# How to get the Usercontrol to keep its size once put on the Page?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Im creating a UWP app. In the App I have created a Usercontrol that has a rectangle of a set size inside it. The size is 700x700. I have also set the Usercontrol to 700x700.

How I thought it would work is that when the developer places the Usercontrol onto the Page then a Usercontrol will appear with a size of 700x700.

However the Usercontrol is appearing with a size of 100x100!

This is the code from the Page after I double-clicked the Usercontrol in the Toolbar to add it to the Page.

```
<Custom:Control HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="254,158,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

*Note the Height and Width are 100x100!*

I have set the Height and Width properties of the Usercontrol to 700x700 in the XAML and the class constructor. Nothing changes!

I have set the set the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties for all the Child controls in the Usercontrol. Nothing changes!

This is the Usercontrol XAML

```
<Usercontrol
    x:Class="Circles.CustomControls.Control"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Circles.CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="700" Height="700">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Canvas x:Name="Container" Background="Transparent" Width="700" Height="700" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Rectangle x:Name="Card" Stroke="Black" Width="700" Height="700" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the Usercontrol code-behind

```
public sealed partial class Control : Usercontrol
{
   public Control()
   {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      this.Height = 700;
      this.Width = 700;
   }

}
```

I expect that when a developer places the Usercontrol onto the Page then a Usercontrol of size 700x700 will appear.

***UPDATE 1***
Here are some pictures

[Image1 - This shows the issue with the bounding rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG9oo.png)

[Image2 - This show the DatePicker control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvyY0.png)

Both a Usercontrol and a Datepicker control where added to the Page in the same way.

- *Select the control from the Toolbox and drag it to the Page.*

**Image1 is the Usercontrol**

1. The smaller rectangle 100x100
2. The size in the control is set to 700x700 for both the Usercontrol and the Canvas
3. Canvas size shows as 700x700
4. VS properties windows show 100x100
5. VS Page XAML shows Height and Width as 100x100

**Image2 is the Datepicker**

1. The bounding rectangle follows the visible contours of the internal controls
2. VS properties window has the default size set

@Nico Zhu - MSFT and @Faenrig - I hope this illustrates my issue. If what you have done is working then I would love to know what I have done wrong or am not doing

Comment: Why isn't there `InitializeComponent();` in the Control constructor?

Comment: Sorry about the it was a bad copy paste edit on my part

Comment: I checked your screen why you set `TargetAirRiFle2` width as `100` where in the Grid ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the Usercontrol to keep its size once put on the Page?

The size of `Usercontrol` will be constrained by it's parent container. if the parent size was limited to 100*100, Your `Usercontrol` will be resized. so please edit the parent container.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="700" Width="700">
    <local:CustomLabel/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried that but it does not solve they "How to get the Usercontrol to keep its size once put on the Page?" question.
When you double click or drag the Usercontrol from the Toolbox it is placed in the Page like this
```<Custom:Control HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="254,158,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>```

Comment: So what I need to work out is how to get it from pre-populating Height and Width properties.

Comment: I tried drag the custom control from tool box, But I could not repro this issue, please provide us a mini code sample that could reproduce this issue.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue, too. I simply couldn't so an example would help. In my case I tried several sizes of the MainWindow and the control on it.
The funniest was MainWindow and the control at 700x700, but the control was in a Stackpanel of 100x100 size. You could clearly see the control wasn't fully shown by a border top and left.
Still the size values were adapted correctly so the issue is quite too broad right now.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT -  I have posted some Images of what I see. It also shows the code.

Comment: @Faenrig -  I have posted some Images of what I see. It also shows the code.

Comment: You could try to use the d:DesignHeight and d.DesignWidth to set the size of the UserControl. They are for the Designer and the Height and Width are for runtime.